# how windows will do auto java update checks?

Tags: java, windows, updates

First of all sorry for my poor English.

I want to know how the **windows** will do **auto java update check** behind the User Interface ?

The **UI** will just react based on our input which is in the link , http://java.com/en/download/help/java_update.xml#howto .

But , how windows checks the updates programmatically.

I wrote a small program in **java** ,

```
public class JavaLatestVersion {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(
                    "http://java.com/applet/JreCurrentVersion2.txt").openStream())) ;
                    String fullVersion = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("fullVersion : "+fullVersion);
                    String version = fullVersion.split("_")[0];
                    String revision = fullVersion.split("_")[1];
                    System.out.println("Version " + version + " revision " + revision);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**My questions :**

**1.** Is the above program is the reliable way to get the latest **java version** ? Or any other standard way to get the latest java version *(Not in the computer)* ?

**2.** Is **windows** use the same way to determine the `latest java version` ?

**3.** Is **windows** use this link for updates http://java.com/applet/JreCurrentVersion2.txt ?

Any one know the secret code behind how windows will check for latest java updates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows doesn't check if your Java installation is up to date. Java checks if it is up to date. I don't have any details, but it communicates with a server, and checks if the current version matches with the latest version available.

Comment: Yes . But I want to know the communication URL for getting the current latest version.

Comment: Why do you want to get the latest version? Let's say your code requires and runs with Java 1.7.0_21 but the newest version is 1.7.0_65. What's the advantage of the new version? Do you think people can install their own version on a corporate machine?

Answer (score 0):

Checking for Java updates is done by **Java Auto Updater**. It is ordinary application (which is ran when Windows starts up).

1. Yes, it is reliable way to get the latest version of Java (as updater can not only update Java, it can also update itself). But pay attention to *firewall/group policy* settings which can prohibit updater to access the Web.
2. Windows doesn't update Java.
3. Only debugging **Java Auto Updater** can help to determine what URL it uses.

Unfortunately, **Java Auto Updater** has only graphical interface and hides all work behind the scenes. So finding a "secret code" is not easy to do. All the more in many cases reverse-engineering non-open source software is illegal from a license point of view.

URL that you provided above doesn't works. Because it says `8.0_51`. But latest version of Java on [Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) page is `8u65 / 8u66`.

Seems that latest available version (as plain text) can be determined only by fetching http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html web page, then parsing it, handling cases when page is moved to another location, etc.